# How to set another ViewController as a delegate of AlertView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uialertview

I wanted to know if it is possible to set Alert View delegate as some other ViewController.
The reason is because I intend to implement a certain action based upon the alert view button pressed by the user.

Here is what I am trying to do:-

1] Declared `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in the view controller.h file where i need to implement alertView delegate method.

2]This is how my alertView is declared in AppDelegate.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
      if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
     {
         alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Message" message:@"Click switch to check out" delegate:rosterListController cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Switch ", nil];
        [alertView show];
     }
 }
```

3] Now i want to implement alertView delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex` in another View Controller , but it doesn't get called.

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel button pressed");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does rosterListController exist or it's nil?

Comment: ohk....roster list controller is nil....

Comment: Well, in order for someone to do something for you, that person needs to exist, doesn't he? So if you want your viewController to handle the delegate method, you need to create it (alloc, init) before you set it as delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the AppDelegate the AlertView Delegate, since it's the App Delegate which presents the Alter View. It makes no sense to use a random unrelated view controller. If you have the strong desire to do this anyway, consider that something is wrong with your design and application logic.

Alternatively, you might create a new class, which becomes the delegate. The sole purpose of this class is to handle the Alert View events, and possibly passing data back and force between the presenter and the alert view. You may define a protocol, which defines the minimum API a presenter must fulfill in order to communicate with the delegate handler.

For each presenter which presents this alert view, have an ivar for the delegate object. When you present the Alert View, no matter which presenter, create and initialize the delegate object and set it as the delegate. When the alert view will be dismissed, release the delegate object.

Note, that the delegate object may need a reference to the presenter, in order to handle dismiss events.

Answer (score 0):

set `rosterListController` delegate at global place and ,than set alertview delegate to its `rosterListController` delegate. Alertview delgate function will be called in the view where its delegate is set.

```
GlobalSpace

id rosterDelegate;
+(void)setRosterDelegate:(id)_delegate{
_rosterDelegate=_delegat;
}
+(id)getRosterDelegate{
return _rosterDelegate;
}
```

Now in your `rosterListController` Class set your delegate like this

```
[GlobalSpace setRosterDelegate:self];
```

and your alertView like this

```
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Message" message:@"Click switch to check out" delegate:[GlobalSpace getRosterDelegate] cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Switch ", nil];
```